# Отдать куки в curl при повторном обращении

Tags: php, curl

Есть код, ставит пишет куки:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://site.ru');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'MSE');
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($data);
?>
```

Как сделать что бы при повторном обращении к нему отдавались записанные куки?

Comment: Вы уже используете стандартный вариант работы с куками, указав одним файлом куда записывать куки и откуда их брать в случае необходимости.

Comment: Если есть куки, которые записались с прошлой сессии в файл `cookie.txt`, то Curl возьмет их автоматически. Следует обратить внимание, что обязательно должно пройти `curl_close();` с предыдущей сессии

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё должно работать и так с вашим кодом. Опция `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` говорит, что надо *записывать* куки в файл `"cookie.txt"`, а опция `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` говорит, что надо *читать* куки из этого файла. У вас обе опции указаны, поэтому должно и читать, и писать.